# How do I listen to a file's events in local directory in Flutter?

Tags: file, flutter, stream, filesystems, listener

I wonder if we could listen to a `path` and if the file is created / changed then it can trigger something like `onData`.

Something like:

```
File file = File(path);

file.listen((){});

file.onData((file) => doSomethingWithTheFile);
```

Comment: tried `File.watch`?

Comment: I got this error message: `FileSystemException: File system watching is not supported on this platform, path = ''`
Actually the path is not empty and has the right directory.
 According to documentation it work in Windows, Linux and OSX. But seems not working in iOS and Android. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html)